# Getting properties from one class into another in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

This is my code for the Main class:

```
package {
import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Main extends Sprite{

    private var ball:Ball;
    private var paddle:Paddle;

    public function Main():void {
        addToUI();
        beginCode();
    }

    public function beginCode():void {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, move);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, hitTest);
    }

    public function move(event:Event):void {
        ball.move();
    }


    private function hitTest(event:Event):void {
        if(ball.hitTestObject(paddle)){
            vy = -20;
        }
    }

    private function addToUI():void {
        paddle = new Paddle();
        ball = new Ball();
        addChild(paddle);
        addChild(ball);

        paddle.x = 50;
        paddle.y = 200;

        ball.x = 75;
        ball.y = 100;
    }
}
```

}

This is my code for the Ball class:

```
package {

import flash.display.*;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Ball extends MovieClip {
    public var vy:Number = 10;

    public function move():void {
        vy += 2;
        this.y += vy;
    }

    /*
    public function hitTest(paddle):void {
        if(this.hitTestObject(paddle)){
            vy = -20;
        }
    }
    */
}
```

}

I'm having a hard time getting the collision test to work properly. When I use f. ex. use

```
trace("Collision works")
```

in the hitTest function, it responds properly. But I am not able to change the vy-property. I've also tried to write the hitTest in the Ball class, but then the compiler tells me that the property paddle is undefined.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `vy` for the ball instance:

```
private function hitTest(event:Event):void {
    if(ball.hitTestObject(paddle)){
        ball.vy = -20;
    }
}
```